# Codeigniter redirect not working in website

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

i have encountered not working redirect in one of my method. but the rest redirect is working.
by the way in my localhost that redirect is working but when i put it in my site to test it. it did not pass to that redirect instead it stayed in signup_validation and still received email verification in my email.

```
public function signup_validation() {

    $account = array(
        'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password')),
        'firstname' => strip_tags($this->input->post('firstname')),

        'lastname' => strip_tags($this->input->post('lastname')),
        'contact_number' => $this->input->post('contact_number'),
        'home_address' => strip_tags($this->input->post('home_address')),

        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),

        'g-recaptcha-response' => $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response')
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[account.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First name', 'required|callback_alpha_dash_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last name', 'required|callback_alpha_dash_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_number', 'Contact Number', 'required|callback_number|min_length[7]|max_length[11]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('home_address', 'required|callback_address');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tac', 'Terms and Condition', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('g-recaptcha-response', 'Recaptcha', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('number', 'The %s must be a number');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('address','The %s must contain only letters, period, comma, spaces and dash.');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Email address is already used.');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_dash_space','The %s must contain only letters, period, spaces, and dash.');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->register();
    } else {
        $recaptcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (!empty($recaptcha)) {
                $response = $this->recaptcha->verifyResponse($recaptcha);
                if (isset($response['success']) and $response['success'] === true) {
                   $this->MainModel->add_account();
                    redirect('main/email_sent', 'refresh');     
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second parameter of `redirect()`, when set the second parameter to `'refresh'` this method will just refresh current page.

```
redirect('main/email_sent');
```

Comment: i've tried it too still when i press the register button it will stock in base_url().'main/signup_validation' and it doesnt proceed to the redirect. and also when im working in localhost that redirect works.

Comment: @EdgarOng   try to `echo` the `uri `you passed  and die the script after `echo` in definition of `redirect` ， find out if the `url` printed is what you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

remove second parameter ('refresh') from

```
redirect('main/email_sent', 'refresh');
```

Just Excited to know if it works.

Comment: it is also said a while ago and  sad to say  still doenst work.